# como formatear día de la semana con acento

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt5

estoy intentando dar formato a un campo de un registro de Mysql que tiene el formato fecha_hora y cuando lo intento mostrar con el día de la semana (hoy-miércoles y supongo el sábado) me muestra un símbolo raro.

```
    rs.execute(query)
    reg = rs.fetchone()
    #print (reg[0],reg[1],reg[2],reg[3])
    #<class 'datetime.datetime'> <class 'int'> <class 'int'> <class 'int'>
    #'2022-02-22 12:50:00' formato del registro en mysql
    #'x- mi�rcoles 23 de febrero de 2022 12:50'
    self.leFecha_Hora.setText(format(reg[0],'%A %d de %B de %Y %H:%M'))
```

aunque se ve que parece la fecha y hora de hoy, es un registro mysql. Lo he intentado con strptime y strftime, pero marcan error de formato. Esto lo tengo en otra parte del código
y funciona bien ...

```
QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString("dddd d 'de' MMMM 'de' yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```

esto si funciona para la fecha y hora de hoy.

No sé que mas hacer para solucionarlo, os agradecería una ayuda.

Comment: Es un problema de encoding. Asegurate de que tu base de datos usa el mismo encoding que python (utf8 por defecto)

Comment: Gracias, así lo he hecho, pero... hasta el SÁBADO no puedo confirmarlo :-)